# Pathfinder Effect via Pathfinder Panel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I try to solve some "enigmatic" issue with the Pathfinder panel used along Alt/Option button as Ai suggests -

[image]

The [help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6462a.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-645aa) explains as follows -

> Apply a Pathfinder effect using the Pathfinder panel Select the
> objects to which you want to apply the effect. To apply a Pathfinder
> effect to a group or layer, target the group or layer.
>
> In the Pathfinder panel, click a pathfinder button (in the bottom
> row), or Alt‑click (Windows) or Option‑click (Mac OS) a Shape Mode
> button (in the top row).

However, I cannot achieve any compound shape using Option+click on Pathfinder panel (as opposite to applying pathfinder effects) - I dont see any changes in the appearance panel also (no any live effects I mean).

What do I miss?

Ai 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> behavior changed at roughly CS4 (if I'm remembering versions correctly). I don't know if Adobe corrected or updated the help files accordingly (they often do not).

***The difference is in how the Pathfinder operation is applied and whether or not results are expanded.***

In Illustrator CS6, the default behavior of the **Pathfinder Panel** buttons is to apply the operation and then *expand* the results. This leaves the resulting base shapes only.

The **Pathfinder Effect** menu item has the opposite default behavior. The **Pathfinder Effect** applies the pathfinder operation but ***does not*** expand the results. This leaves the original object paths in tact and only *visually* changes the appearance.

When the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> is held down and a **Pathfinder Panel** button is clicked it essentially makes the **Pathfinder Panel** buttons operate similarly to the **Pathfinder Effect**. That is, the Panel operations are **not** expanded by default if you hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key when clicking the Panel buttons. (Note with CS4 or earlier the default behavior is the *opposite* of this.)

The image you posted is slightly confusing because all this *only applies to the Shape modes* and clearly, those three ellipses have not had any shape operations performed upon them because the result would be objects of a single color.

[image]

Note the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key has no function when choosing a Pathfinder *Effect* from the menu. It only alters the Panel button behavior.

Comment: How do you perform the operation technically  - I select the grouped objects then press Alt and simultaneously click on the Intersect in the Pathfinder panel - nothing happens... ???

Comment: The panel buttons won't have any effect with Option/Alt on a group. Groups are seen as one item. For groups, the Effect menu item is more appropriate if you want the "clipped" appearance the Option/Alt key normally provides.